# RTF library capable of editing and formatting text programatically

Tags: .net, dom, rtf

I'm looking for RTF libraries capable of editing and formatting text programatically. DOM styled document parsers and editors really will make things easy. Found two generally discussed parsers, but they don't fit my requirements:

http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/?page_id=57 - the DOM is not implemented fully to abstract various details
http://www.sinoreport.net/RTFDomParser_Details.aspx - the DOM model although implemented satisfactorily, but it lacks a way to write out the RTF text

So what I'm looking for is a RTF library, capable of parsing and creating DOM tree, allows editing this structure and then saving the modified structure.

I'm having a rather interesting conversation [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/209bae91-6be9-4f80-855a-4c600e7e8dcd); just in case you guys wanna comment on these lines.

Comment: I had to do some stuff with RTF once and used this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nrtftree/

Comment: I had to do some stuff with RTF once and used this one: http://sourceforge.net/projects/nrtftree/

Answer (score 1):

We are using Aspose.Words for stuff like this. It's not free, but works pretty well.

http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx

Let me know if you have more specific questions or have a look at their documentation.

Comment: We also did zero out on it earlier, but didn't give it a try when a guy with hands-on experience with this library told us that it didn't work out well for him.